# Split string with REGEX based on space and optional 3rd string-token

Tags: java, regex

I have a file with lines having the string pattern

`(digit)(one-or-more-space-seperator)(word-possibly-starting-and-ending-with-@)(one-or-more-space-seperator)(more-words-seperated-by-spaces)`

Eg:

```
1 NAME first name

2  NAME   last name

3 @silly@  i am nuts

4 @lilly@
```

The resulting output of the regex-matchers for each of the lines above should respectively be as below:

```
[1, NAME, first name]

[2, NAME, last name]

[3, @silly@, i am nuts]

[4, @lilly@]
```

If you succeed in finding out a regex, I'd like to know how you went about making one..

I get stuck badly when it comes to regex :(

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You have basically given the schema already, which can be translated to RegEx easily. Where is the problem?

Comment: Here is my attempted regex: "^([0-9]*)\\s*(\b.*\b)\\s*(.*)"

Comment: Don't use split, use `Pattern` and `Matcher#find()`

Comment: tried. find() returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class Module1{
    public static void main(String[] asd){
        String sourcestring = "1 NAME john smith";
        Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(NAME|@\\w+@)(.*)");
        Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
        int i = 0;
        while (m.find()){
            for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
                System.out.println( "[" + i + "][" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`(\d+) +(\w+|@\w+@) *([\w ]+)?` should do the trick. (replace with double escapes for Java)